# How to resize text in qtip tooltip jquery

Tags: jquery, qtip

i'm using qtip in this way:

```
$('#div').qtip({content:"CONTENT",show: {event: false,ready: true},hide:false,position: {at: 'bottom left'}});
```

My problem is that `CONTENT` to show is too much text and it will cover other part of page. Can i resize text in tooltip? Help me pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.. you could use this in css:

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
   font-size:12px;
}
```